# Change keyboard layout on WSL

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to change to Dvorak on Windows Subsystem for Linux.  I want to do this automatically every time I log in to the WSL session, but only for myself so it doesn't affect any other users on the shared machine.  Vanilla linux commands are not working, for example `localectl` results in

```
Failed to create bus connection: No such file or directory
```

and `setxkbmap`:

```
Cannot open display "default display"
```

This is Ubuntu WSL on Windows Server 2019, and if it matters I'm connecting to the Windows machine over remote desktop from a Mac.

Comment: You are not running `X` in WSL I assume?

Comment: Correct, just command line.

Comment: Do you have administrative access on the Windows Server?  If not, is the administrator willing to do installation/configuration for you?  By the way, there's really not likely to be much "Linux" in the answer to your question.  Might be better to request that this be moved over to Super User.

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds if I don't have admin access I can get it, or get access to an administrator.  You're saying the solution is doing something in Windows?  I don't want to change Windows keyboard settings because I don't want to risk forgetting to switch back to Qwerty, or having it accidentally changed, and then the machine is unusable for anyone else.  The fix must only affect WSL, and only my user within WSL.

Comment: Right - I understood that.  What are you using WSL for?  Are you running any Windows GUI app from WSL or just using CLI?  I'm thinking that if you `ssh`'d into WSL from the Mac, then your Mac keyboard settings would be in effect.

Comment: There is a need to run Windows applications.  I had no idea it would be possible to SSH directly to WSL, I will look into that.  It looks like this solution would allow both RDP to Windows and SSH to WSL: https://jeetblogs.org/post/sshing-into-a-windows-wsl-linux-subsystem/ as long as I can get a port open. Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

Found this way to SSH to WSL.  It doesn't directly answer my question but accomplishes my goal.

First, open an admin PowerShell prompt (Start menu, type PowerShell, hold ctrl+shift, and hit enter) type this:

```
Get-WindowsCapability -Online | ? Name -like 'OpenSSH*'

Name  : OpenSSH.Client~~~~0.0.1.0
State : Installed

Name  : OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
State : NotPresent
```

See how I have the Client and not the OpenSSH Server? Add it:

```
Add-WindowsCapability -Online -Name OpenSSH.Server~~~~0.0.1.0
```

Now either start the SSHD service, or set it to start automatically:

```
Start-Service sshd
Get-Service sshd
```

or automatic:

```
Set-Service -Name sshd -StartupType 'Automatic'
```

Source: https://www.hanselman.com/blog/the-easy-way-how-to-ssh-into-bash-and-wsl2-on-windows-10-from-an-external-machine